# Swift Error libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new in Swift and I need your help.

```
    lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Userprofile")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("handleSelectProfileImageView")))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return imageView
}()

func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker .delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        self.present(picker, animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            profileImageView.image = image
        }else
        {
            //ERROR
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        print("canceled picker")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

And then I get this error:

> 017-01-04 19:39:18.889 ChatUp[7484:136643] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ChatUp.LoginController handleSelectProfileImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe94cc0c0c0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a41ad4b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109e7c21e objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a48af04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3a0005 ___forwarding_** + 1013
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a39fb88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000010b48d409 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 57
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010b4951a8 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010b492c77 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 227
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010b491f03 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 891
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010b47df7e _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1395
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010b47d9c3 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 521
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010b47cba6 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 286
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010afc2c1d -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3989
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010af6f9ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
>       14  UIKit                               0x000000010b75c72d **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010b755463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3bf761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3a498c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3a3e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3a3884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>       20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e329a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
>       21  UIKit                               0x000000010af51c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       22  ChatUp                              0x000000010845d42f main + 111
>       23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d1c368d start + 1
>       24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: on the first time the program was good then i get the problem

Comment: `Selector(("handleSelectProfileImageView"))` Why are there so much parenthesis?